# Alternating colour in listview items

Tags: c#

What i am trying to do here is loop a bunch of .csv files split the data, and  then put the data in a listview, this is all working fine:

```
        private void BtnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try {
                RunExtraction();
                listViewMain.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Helpers.DebugLogging("[" + DateTime.Now + "]-[" + ex.ToString() + "]");
            }
        }

        private void ProcessCsvFile(string CsvLocation, string CsvFile) {
            try {
                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"backlinks\data.txt");
                string[] hosts_list = new string[lines.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
                {
                    hosts_list[i] = (lines[i].Split('|')[0]);
                }

                using (var reader = new StreamReader(CsvLocation))
                {
                    while(reader.Peek() != -1) { 
                        string line = reader.ReadLine();
                        List<string> lineValues = line.Split(',').ToList();
                        if (!lineValues[0].StartsWith("Time")) {
                            ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(lineValues[0].Replace(@"""", " "));
                            lv.SubItems.Add(lineValues[1].Replace(@"""", " "));
                            lv.SubItems.Add(lineValues[2]);
                            listViewMain.Items.Add(lv);
                        }
                    }
                    countToolStrip.Text = listViewMain.Items.Count.ToString() + " extracted ...";
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Helpers.DebugLogging("[" + DateTime.Now + "]-[" + ex.ToString() + "]");
            }
        }
```

What i don't know how to do is alternate the colour between say green and pink for example, like this in the listview:

- csv data = green
- csv data = pink
- csv data = green
- csv data = pink
- etc

In the listview, i don't need every row alternate, but every csv file block of information imported, they are different sizes in length, I cannot think of a way to do it, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't shared some parts of your code, I assume `RunExtraction` is calling `ProcessCsvFile` in a loop over csv files. Just add a new argument `color` to `ProcessCsvFile`. In `RunExtraction`, alternate it before calling `ProcessCsvFile`. Pseudocode below:

```
RunExtraction()
{
    var colors = new List<Color>() { Colors.Green, Colors.Pink }; // add more if you want
    var colorIndex = 0;
    var csvLocation = "<some-path>";
    foreach (var csvFile in csvFiles) {
        var color = colors[colorIndex % colors.Count]; // allows you use more than two colors to alternate
        ProcessCsvFile(csvLocation, color); // CsvFile is not used, so it is removed
        colorIndex++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I forgot to share this portion of code, pretty much the same. It worked.

Comment: glad to be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You may just use a simple counter inside the loop and check if it's even/odd

```
var counter = 1;
while (/* ... */)
{
  // ...
  if (counter%2 == 0) lv.ForeColor = Color.Green;
  // ...
  counter++;
}
```

Comment: That would colour each alternate row, what i'm looking to do is colour each import of a .csv file, if a .csv has 87 lines those 87 would be green, the next one imported would be say pink, then the next one green kinda thing, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through GridView using `DataGridViewRow` and check if the row is even then Green else Pink for odd rows. Just like this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)

if (row.Index % 2==0 )
{
   row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;    
}
else{
   row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Pink; 
}
```